# Angle between two vectors

Tags: vectors

If |A+B|=|A-B| then what would be the angle between A and B?

I tried to solve and could find 180. Since A+B implies that vectors  are inclined at angle 0 and A-B implies vectors are inclined at 180. Now the angle between them should be 180. But it's answer in a answer key is 90. How can it be justified?

Comment: Are we assuming here that both vectors are nonzero?

Comment: @probably_someone yes

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

Note that

$$
|\vect{C}|^2  = \vect{C}\cdot\vect{C}
$$

thefore the equality $|\vect{A} - \vect{B}| = |\vect{A} + \vect{B}|$ is equivalent to $(\vect{A} - \vect{B})\cdot (\vect{A} - \vect{B}) = (\vect{A} + \vect{B})\cdot (\vect{A} + \vect{B})$, expanding this you get

$$
A^2 + B^2 + 2AB\cos\theta = A^2 + B^2 - 2AB\cos\theta
$$

where $A = |\vect{A}|$ and $\theta$ is the angle that $\vect{A}$ and $\vect{B}$ form. *If* both $\vect{A}$ and $\vect{B}$ are not zero, then

$$
\cos\theta = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also understand it without doing the math. You can construct a parallelogram with the two vectors as sides. The sum of the vector is represented by one diagonal of the parallelogram. The difference is represented by the other diagonal. A parallelogram with diagonals of the same size is a rectangle. So the angle should be 90 degrees.